# Can't find openvswitch-brcompat on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: packages, apt, libvirt

Like title says...and if I look into kernel modules I just find openvswitch.ko.
I am on ubuntu 13.10 and I installed

openvswitch-controller
openvswitch-switch openvswitch-datapath-source openvswitch-datapath-dkms

when i try to install openvswitch-brcompat it just says it can't find any package named like that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Bridge compatibility seems to be dropped since OVS 1.10.0

From the [OVS 1.10.0 release note](http://openvswitch.org/releases/NEWS-1.10.0):

> Bridge compatibility support has been removed.  Any uses that
>         rely on ovs-brcompatd will have to stick with Open vSwitch 1.9.x
>         or adapt to native Open vSwitch support (e.g. use ovs-vsctl instead
>         of brctl).

see also: 
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cloudstack-dev/201305.mbox/%3C51A69C22.9090303@stratosphere.co.jp%3E

Comment: Welcome to superuser. When providing an answer rather than simply provide a link can you quote the key information which answers the question. Thanks.